# extract digits from a column and put them in an empty column as an int range in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to iterate over a column('winning_numbers') in a data frame, then take the first and the last digits as a int range in an empty column('win_num_range') line by line using a for loop. I am sure this has been asked before, but I can't find an answer that works given the syntax and methods involved.

````
import pandas as pd 
  
# Define a dictionary containing employee data 
data = {'winning_numbers':['12, 15, 36, 46, 55', '3, 10, 56, 67, 69'], 

#this is ideally what I want the OUTPUT to be below
        'win_num_range':[(12, 55), (3, 69)]} 
  
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# been trying it this way, but I am sure there are any numbers of ways, so please help kindly I am kinda new

for ind, row in df.iterrows():
  df.loc[ind, 'win_num_range'] = lambda x : range(x[0],x[4]),df.loc['winning_numbers'].values```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution:

If you really want the range information in a string format:

```
df['win_num_range'] = df['winning_numbers'].apply(lambda x: 'range(' + str(min(map(int,x.split(',')))) + ', ' + str(max(map(int,x.split(',')))) + ')')
```

If you need as tuple, then you should do like this:

```
df['win_num_range'] = df['winning_numbers'].apply(lambda x: (min(map(int,x.split(','))), max(map(int,x.split(',')))))
```

If you need as range:

```
df['win_num_range'] = df['winning_numbers'].apply(lambda x: range(min(map(int,x.split(','))), max(map(int,x.split(',')))))
```

Use apply and a lambda function to evaluate each row.

split(',') creates a list with the values in winning_numbers column.

This approach allows you to use min and max to deliver the information in your desired format.

Comment: nah looking for int, so I can put it into machine learning easier down the line a bit, but thanks for advice it helped me narrow down my vision

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check if it address your problem.